# Angular UI Grid Edit

Tags: angularjs

I have been using KendoGrid so far for edit, filter and sorting.

Is it possible to use Angular UI  Grid (http://ui-grid.info/) and achieve the result similar to these 2 demos.

These 2 demos are for KendoGrid editing row in Grid.
1.  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline
2.  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These all demo features are possible in Angular UI grid. go through the tutorials given this link.

[click here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable
But it is not similar to Kendo .. I need explicit edit , save and cancel button

Comment: U can use button also there inside grid column there is option for "appScope". You will get some info here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope